# How long does Django's password reset link work?

Tags: python, django, backend

I just want to know after how much time does the link expire.
How long does Django's password reset link work?

Answer (score 2):

there are [two settings that control this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#password-reset-timeout), `PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT` and `PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using django-password-reset.

They are configurable but they expire after 48 hours by default.

[**Password reset links that expire in two days (configurable).**](https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-password-reset/downloads/pdf/latest/#:%7E:text=Password%20reset%20links%20that%20expire%20in%20two%20days%20(configurable).)